# Equality implies equality, name?

Tags: functions

Let $f_1: A \rightarrow F_1$ and $f_2: A \rightarrow F_2$. How would one call the following property of these two functions:

$$\forall a_1, a_2 \in A: f_1(a_1) = f_1(a_2) \Rightarrow f_2(a_1) = f_2(a_2)$$

Does this have something to do with homomorphisms?

Would it be different if the following is also true, if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are totally ordered:

$$\forall a_1, a_2 \in A: f_1(a_1) \ge f_1(a_2) \Rightarrow f_2(a_1) \ge f_2(a_2)$$
$$\forall a_1, a_2 \in A: f_1(a_1) \le f_1(a_2) \Rightarrow f_2(a_1) \le f_2(a_2)$$

Comment: This site uses MathJax for mathematics formatting. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick and thurough guide.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Modified it, so it's easier to read now.

Comment: Seems like it is a generalization of the notation of injectivity. If $f_2$ is the identity, then it is definition of injective.

Comment: (Very slightly more general, you get injectivity as soon as $f_2$ is injective.)